# Counting page visits with javascript and cookies

Tags: javascript, session, variables, cookies

I would like to count a users visit to a site within a session and implement certain functionality based on how many pages the user has visited.  I would like to perform this solely with the use of JavaScript and cookies (using js).

Essentially I would just like to do create `var = 0` and `++` to that same var on each additional visit to another page within that users session.

What is the proper way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable way will be to use AJAX and keep track on the server, associated with the user's session ID.

Each load will need to poll the server, then tell the server to increment the counter.

Comment: it dosn't have to be just ajax other forms of RPC mechanisms will work for updating the cookie, calling eg IMGs, IFRAMEs

Answer (score 0):

You could for example, when the user access the page, First check if the cookie exists, if not then set the cookie name and value and also a (token var) as being set so it dosnt increment on page refreshes.

Then one every other page you require the cookie, again check for cookie and then increment it.

I find a easy to use coolkie script [Cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#script) use.

Comment: Thanks David - This is what I thought I would have to do and was planning on implementing in a similar fashion.  Have you used this method before and confirmed it does work?

Comment: @jnolte, yes i have and it works, but the use can tamper with the values, by adding counts or reducing them

Comment: A more secure way would be to use the a server side language to encrypt/decrypt part of a cookie and or store a hash of known predefined values and include that in a cookie and then check against the received cookie and compare the hashes.