# Count visits to various sites in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to write a Chrome extension that keeps track of how many times one visits a given news site and directs the user to other sites when they've been reading the same one too often. is there a way to do this by looking at the URL on each page load? The pseudocode would be, taking the NY Times as an example:

```
var nytimesCount = 0; 
if (URL includes "nytimes.com")
{
    nytimesCount++;
}
```

Pretty simple. Is there a way to do this? Would using cookies (as per this question: [Counting page visits with javascript and cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331607/counting-page-visits-with-javascript-and-cookies)), or some other method altogether, be easier?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. No, it will not include cookies. Cookies are meant to be used for sharing persistent data with the server. Chrome extensions have much better possibilities to store data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the URL origin with javascript using window.location.origin, and store your data in an array with the indices being the name of the origin, such as:

```
if (typeof visitedSites[window.location.origin] !== 'undefined') {
    visitedSites[window.location.origin] += 1;
} else {
    visitedSites[window.location.origin] = 1;
}
```

In terms of saving the data, I would look into using HTML5 local storage, which will work great in Chrome. http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html